# A sql update query in java where column names are taken dynamically

Tags: java, mysql

In my java program i am altering every column of every row and it is in for loop. So the column name changes as the loop increments. Once the changes are made to the column, i want to update it in the database. I have written update query as below.

```
String query1="update test1.attendence set"+ colname +"= ? where id=?";
PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query1);
pst.setString(1, attchanged);
pst.setInt(2, rownum);
int result=pst.executeUpdate();
```

here colname is a variable which contains the name of the column.
attchanged is the column value after altering it.
rownum is the id attribute of the row

When i execute it i am getting error in syntax.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near '= null where id=2' at line 1
```

Can you tell me the correct syntax to be written here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need a space between `set` and `colname`

```
String query1="update test1.attendence set "+ colname +"= ? where id=?";
PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query1);
pst.setString(1, attchanged);
pst.setInt(2, rownum);
int result=pst.executeUpdate();
```

make sure `colname` is seriously input validated or super safe to use so you dont open yourself up to sql injections

Comment: thank you for recognizing the missing space between set and colname.It is working after giving space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `attchanged` is `null`. I would use a debugger to find the mistake.

Comment: i checked with debugger, attchanged is null. Thank you for bringing it to my notice

Comment: can you tell me reasons why attchanged is null. I am not able to get it.

Comment: i dont know why your attchanged is null. there is not all the code here to see it. i just saw it by your exception 
`right syntax to use near '= null where id=2' at line 1`

and your first **?** is replaced by attchanged:
`pst.setString(1, attchanged);`

so thats why attchanged had to be null.

Answer (score -1):

tried to use the correct format.
String query1=("update test1.attendence set= ? where...");

Comment: are u sure about set=?  because the syntax doesn't contain = after set.

Comment: Where does the column name get inserted here? Note that you can't use SQL parameters for SQL objects, only values.